# Gridview search filter with paging

Tags: javascript, asp.net, search, datagridview, paging

```
function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
            var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
            var rowData;
            for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
                rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
                var styleDisplay = 'none';
                for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
                    if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                        styleDisplay = '';
                    else {
                        styleDisplay = 'none';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
            }
        }
```

i have a gridview and i want to add search filter on it. This code works correctly but search just one page not all rows. How i make this, i discovered but i didn't solve this.